# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" parsing string expression

Tags: java, for-loop, case

I'm trying to parse a string expression (i.e. "6+10*2-5") and calculate the answer as a double using a for-case statement. However I'm getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at Calculator.random(Calculator.java:50)
    at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:210)
```

any ideas?

```
public static double random(String exp) {
    double primeResult = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<exp.length();i++) {
        double left = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0,i));
        double right = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i+1,i+2));
        switch(exp.charAt(i)) {
            case '*':
            primeResult = left * right;
            break;
        case '/':
            primeResult = left / right;
            break;
        case '+':
            primeResult = left + right;
            break;
        case '-':
            primeResult = left - right;
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
        }
        System.out.println(primeResult);
        }
        return primeResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you have to do it that way, a ScriptingEngine would do that for you in fewer lines and more reliably.

Comment: You need to understand that this technique will give the wrong answer even when you fix this problem, because you aren't handling operator precedence. You will evalulate it as `((6+10)*2)-5` rather than `(6+(10*2))-5`. Basically there is nothing here that corresponds to your description 'trying to parse a string expression'. All you're doing is *scanning* it, incorrectly. You need to look up `recursive descent expression parsing`, the Dijkstra 'shunting-yard algorith', etc., or use the `ScriptingEngine` as @assylias suggests.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem has *nothing* to do with `switch`/`case`. The problem is simply that you're trying to parse an empty string as a number. Work out why you've got an empty string, then fix it. (Hint: what do you expect `exp.substring(0, 0)` to return?)

You should also consider what you expect `exp.substring(i+1,i+2)` to return when `i` is `exp.length() - 1` (or even `exp.length() - 2`).

Also, take a step back and consider *why* you thought this was a problem with the `switch`/`case` part. Look at the stack trace - it's not even within the `switch`/`case` statement, but before it. It's very important to be able to diagnose where errors are actually occurring, so you can focus on that and not get distracted by irrelevant parts.

Comment: I'm calling the method from the main using random("5+5")

Comment: @user2297666: Yes, but you're trying to parse `exp.substring(0, i)` - including when `i` is 0.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i+1,i+2));`

Comment: @seeta: Yes, that will be a problem as well - but that's not what caused the original exception.

Answer (score 1):

Jon Skeet has answered your question with very good diagnostic training.

But... I do think your solution to your problem will not work.

If you mentally trace through your code, assuming a proper input of "5+5", the first thing your loop will do is this:

```
double left = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0,i));
double right = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i+1,i+2));
```

With i==0 (first time through the loop), this will translate to:

```
double left = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0,0));
double right = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0+1,0+2));
```

This will IMMEDIATELY get an "empty string" for `exp.substring(0,0)`, which throws the exception in your question.

Oh, and why is your function called "random" if you're evaluating an expression?